# Using more than 4 GB ram in Ubuntu 32 bit

Tags: memory, 32-bit, ubuntu-14.04

I have 6GB ram and my system is Ubuntu 14 & 32 bit. How can I use the ram more than 4GB? please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you can use your 6GB of RAM without doing anything:

There is a technique called PAE (= [Physical Address Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)), which allows you to address 64bit addresses with a 32bit OS. Meanwhile PAE is a requirement for newer Ubuntu versions like `14.04`. And since you have Ubuntu 14.04 32bit and more than 4GB I assume you can use all of it:

Check by this command how much RAM you got:

```
free -m
```

The output will be a small table: Look in line `Mem:` for the column `total`.

In the case you didn't install your OS yet and you receive an error related to PAE during installation, you can look in this guide: [a guide from Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE?action=show&redirect=EnablingPAE).